# How to change All DatePicker's to Custom Format on many forms from external class

Tags: c#, winforms

I've this method to change all DatePicker's formats from one form:

```
public void FormatDateTimePickers()
        {
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                var dateTimePicker = c as DateTimePicker;

                if (dateTimePicker != null)
                {
                    dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                    dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                }
            }
        }
```

But I've too many class that inheritance forms. For example:

class frm1 : Form

class frm2 : Form

class frm3 : Form

Each class have specifics parameters.

I want to create another class with the method to change the DateTimePickers formats and call it on each form class that i've.

So, I tryied:

clsWinFormsGeneric.cls:

```
public partial class clsWinFormsGeneric : Form
    {
        public void FormatDateTimePickers(object customform)
        {
            foreach (Control c in customform.Controls)
            {
                var dateTimePicker = c as DateTimePicker;

                if (dateTimePicker != null)
                {
                    dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                    dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and in frm1.class:

```
clsWinFormsGeneric.FormatDateTimePickers(this);
```

But i got error: Object doesn't have Controls property.

What could I do, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For your code, just change the parameter from object to From :

```
public void FormatDateTimePickers(Form customform)
{
    foreach (Control c in customform.Controls)
    {
        var dateTimePicker = c as DateTimePicker;

        if (dateTimePicker != null)
        {
            dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        }
    }
}
```

### I advise you to do another approach:

The straight forward solution for me is to create a use control that holds only a `DatePicker` and in the constructor set the format.

```
public partial class CustomDatePicker : UserControl
{
    public CustomDatePicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    }
}
```

Another way that i don't prefer, is to use a `BaseForm` that all you forms inherit from, and put your loop inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the parameter customForm is of type object, which does not have a property named Controls. Try changing the parameter type:

```
public void FormatDateTimePickers(Form customform)
{
    foreach (Control c in customform.Controls)
    {
        var dateTimePicker = c as DateTimePicker;
        if (dateTimePicker != null)
        {
            dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        }
    }
}
```